# Distinct where statement getting clobbered

Tags: sqlite, distinct, where-clause

From this database stucture ...

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    powId INTEGER,
    userId INTEGER,
    timeStart DATETIME,
    timeEnd DATETIME,
    points NUMERIC,
    COUNTYNUM NUMERIC,
--  FOREIGN KEY(powId) REFERENCES points_power(powId)
--  FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(userId)
    UNIQUE(userId, timeStart, COUNTYNUM) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
```

With this data ...

```
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('1','7','2','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('2','7','4','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('3','7','12','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('4','7','16','2016-12-31T19:29:23-0500','2016-12-31T20:29:23-0500','2','201612311929');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('5','7','585','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('6','7','2','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('7','7','12','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('9','7','11','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('10','7','593','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('11','7','14','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('12','7','13','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('13','7','11','2017-01-02T13:50:48-0500','2017-01-02T14:50:48-0500','2','201701021350');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('14','7','16','2017-01-02T15:46:07-0500','2017-01-02T16:46:07-0500','2','201701021546');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('15','7','16','2017-01-01T00:33:46-0500','2017-01-01T01:33:46-0500','2','201701010033');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('16','7','2','2017-01-02T13:50:48-0500','2017-01-02T14:50:48-0500','2','201701021350');
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('17','13','1','2017-01-02T17:00:00-0500','2017-01-02T21:00:00-0500','1',NULL);
INSERT INTO "points" ("rowid","powId","userId","timeStart","timeEnd","points","COUNTYNUM") VALUES ('18','13','2','2017-01-02T17:00:00-0500','2017-01-02T21:00:00-0500','1',NULL);
```

And using this query

`SELECT DISTINCT powId, timeStart, timeEnd FROM points WHERE userId != 1;`

I'm not getting the result that I want.

The last two entries in the database what I'm looking at right now. `userId` is set for the first of those two entries, but the second entry masks the `userId` and it still returns that distinct row now. Is there anything I can do to that query to make it not return ANY distinct row where that `userId` is within the DISTINCT set?

I basiclly want to get all points that the `userId` is not assigned. How do I do that? I figured it would be this simple, but it's not.

**Please, only SQLite answers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check all (other) rows with the same column values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT powId,
                timeStart,
                timeEnd
FROM points
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM points AS p2
                  WHERE p2.powId     = points.powId
                    AND p2.timeStart = points.timeStart
                    AND p2.timeEnd   = points.timeEnd
                    AND p2.userId = 1);
```